# multithreading or multiprocessing or asynchronous for a building a NMS - perfomance

Tags: python, multithreading, performance, asynchronous, multiprocessing

I am trying to build a NMS (Network Management System) backend whose sole purpose is following:

1. Periodically monitor 15K-30K devices using SNMP, telnet, ssh connections to devices and various I/O requests to third-party softwares using sql, soap, and rest api.
2. So, basically fetching the data for each device from various third-party softwares, connecting to device via SSH/Telnet/SNMP/etc. and then updating our database with the data fetched (lots of I/O processing)

In order to build such a software, I have following questions (would like advice from the experts in programming):

1. Regardless of programming language, what is the most performance effective (in terms of speed) way to build this tool and why?

   a.  Multiprocessing

   a.  Multithreading

   a.  Asynchronous programming (like node.js or Python's twisted)
2. Currently, I am using Python to build it out with multiprocessing. Its very memory intensive, but speed seems to be fast enough (not sure though considering it takes 20 hrs for polling 30K devices from various sources). But I want a 2nd opinion, if I were to use Python should I try multithreading or Asynchronous programming and will the speed improve?
3. Finally, regarding programming language, does it truly matter which programming language I use in the backend for this purpose? I have experience in Node.js and Python, and open to other languages only if I get a huge boost in my performance.

My setup is a Ubuntu Server quad-core, 4GB RAM.

Comment: Firstly... this is a broad question. Secondly, do you plan on leveraging existing graph management frameworks instead of building it yourself?  (As an author of a graph framework myself, I should take my own advice… but 10 years ago this was not as much of an option as it is today).  There are a few such frameworks in python that you could leverage… each providing high-level access to multiprocessing, multithreading, and asynchronous computing.  A few of these packages also provide ash and socket connectivity as well.

Lastly, it's usually best to script the whole package in a single language.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply... Yes I understand this is more of a broad question, but I wanted to make it specific towards Python and comparing which way to scale for I/O processing.

Regarding your answer, I am not familiar with graph management framework. Could you please provide a simple example package?

Yes, I agree regarding one language for building a package, but with SDN API comping along for various vendors, it won't be a option in my opinion

Comment: For some examples: `pathos` (mine: at https://github.com/uqfoundation), `IPython-parallel` (part of `IPython`), and `scoop`.  There are also a few others that are relatively newer.